# Installing mySQL on Windows

Tags: mysql

Downloaded and run the installer from https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/

After installing it opened MySQL Workbench but I can't connect to `localhost` (I notice that the installer didn't ask for a `root` password), and I can't see a MySQL service in `services.msc`.

Is there something that I need to do -- in addition to running the installer -- to get it to work? (And is this documented?)

Answer (score -1):

Run the installer for a second time and choose *Reconfigure*.